# C++ Compiler Error 2086 redefinition

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, redefinition

I have a `.cpp` file that must include `Console.h`. In the file I'm trying to create a map (used later on for a game).

Error C2086: 'int nMapArray[15][20]: redefinition

```
#include "Console.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// Map dimensions
#define MAP_WIDTH   20
#define MAP_HEIGHT  15


// Tile Types
#define TILE_FLOOR      0
#define TILE_WALL       1


// Map declaration
int nMapArray[ MAP_HEIGHT ][ MAP_WIDTH ];

// Map Layout
int nMapArray[ MAP_HEIGHT ][ MAP_WIDTH ]= 
{
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};
```

I know that I'm only supposed to declare `nMapArray` once but I'm not sure which one to discard. If I discard `int nMapArray[ MAP_HEIGHT ][ MAP_WIDTH ];` then it will generate two errors:
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
and
LNK1120: unresolved externals

Did a bit of googling but I still can't find the fix so help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Ok so following the advice of many to get rid of the first inisialisation. From here I get two errors:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class IConsole & __thiscall Win32Console::Color(unsigned short)" (?Color@Win32Console@@UAEAAVIConsole@@G@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl DrawTile(int,int)" (?DrawTile@@YAXHH@Z)

and

error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Full code:

```
#include "Console.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// Map dimensions
#define MAP_WIDTH   20
#define MAP_HEIGHT  15


// Tile Types
#define TILE_FLOOR      0
#define TILE_WALL       1

// Map Layout
int nMapArray[ MAP_HEIGHT ][ MAP_WIDTH ]= 
{
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};

void DrawMap( void );
bool IsPassable( int x, int y );
void DrawTile( int x, int y );

int main( void )
{
    console.SetTitle( "Article Two Demo" );

    // Declare the player's position
    int nPlayerX = 4;
    int nPlayerY = 4;

    // Main game loop
    while( true )
    {
        // Draw the map
        DrawMap();

        // Draw the player to the screen
        console.Color( RED );
        console.Position( nPlayerX, nPlayerY );
        console << '@';

        // Input phase - Wait for the player to do something
        KEYPRESS sKeyPress = console.WaitForKeypress();

        // Process the input
        switch( sKeyPress.eCode )
        {
            // Move up
            case CONSOLE_KEY_UP:
                // Can we move to the tile above?
                if( IsPassable(nPlayerX, nPlayerY-1) )
                {
                    // Move up
                    nPlayerY--;
                }
                break;

            // Move left
            case CONSOLE_KEY_LEFT:
                // Can we move to the tile to the left of the player?
                if( IsPassable(nPlayerX-1, nPlayerY) )
                {
                    // Move left
                    nPlayerX--;
                }
                break;

            // Move right
            case CONSOLE_KEY_RIGHT:
                // Can we move to the tile to the right of the player
                if( IsPassable(nPlayerX+1, nPlayerY ) )
                {
                    // Move right
                    nPlayerX++;
                }
                break;

            // Move down
            case CONSOLE_KEY_DOWN:
                // Can we move to the tile below the player?
                if( IsPassable(nPlayerX, nPlayerY+1) )
                {
                    // Move down
                    nPlayerY++;
                }
                break;

            // Escape key
            case CONSOLE_KEY_ESCAPE:
                // Quit the program
                return 0;

            // Ignore any other keys
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    // If execution gets here, the program is done
    return 0;
}

// IsPassable Function ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  This function analyzes the coordinates of the map array specified and returns
//  true if the coordinate is passable (able for the player to occupy), false if not.
//
bool IsPassable( int x, int y )
{
    // Before we do anything, make darn sure that the coordinates are valid
    if( x < 0 || x >= MAP_WIDTH || y < 0 || y >= MAP_HEIGHT )
        return false;

    // Store the value of the tile specified
    int nTileValue = nMapArray[y][x];

    // Return true if it's passable
    if( nTileValue == TILE_FLOOR)
        return true;

    return false;
}

// DrawMap Function //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  This function draws the entire map to the screen.
//
void DrawMap( void )
{
    for( int y = 0; y < MAP_HEIGHT; y++ )
    {
        for( int x = 0; x < MAP_WIDTH; x++ )
        {
            DrawTile(x, y);
        }
    }   
}

// DrawTile Function /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  Draws a map tile for the map coordinates specified.
//
void DrawTile( int x, int y )
{
    console.Position( x, y );
    switch( nMapArray[y][x] )
    {
        case TILE_FLOOR:
            console.Color( GREY );
            console << '.';
            break;

        case TILE_WALL:
            console.Color( GREY );
            console << '#';
            break;

    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

In `Console.h` I haven't put the layout in (because I'm not entirely sure how to do that).

Comment: Unless the no-doubt time-consuming effort you put into declaring that expansion is ok to throw out the window, delete the first one. Is it in a header? if it is, then `extern` it. If not, get rid of it.

Comment: 1. What's the (relevant) content of `Console.h`? What `LNK2019` do you get when you remove `int nMapArray[ MAP_HEIGHT ][ MAP_WIDTH ];` (which is the one you should be removing)?

Comment: Actually, that's two separate issues. The double definition is a compilation error. When you (correctly) remove `int nMapArray[ MAP_HEIGHT ][ MAP_WIDTH ];`, the compilation succeeds and the process can go to the next stage, which is linking. This then produces linker errors (`LNK2019`). If you post them, we might help, but they're probably unrelated to `nMapArray`.

Comment: Yeah I've just changed it around, not sure how you want me to put it in the header, @WhozCraig

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the first one, the one without the initialisation.

That solves the compiler issue, the linker errors are another matter. The reason they appear is simply because the compilation phase is working once the double declaration is fixed.

Then I suggest you post another question with more details on the linker problems.